# 'In a form' or 'of a form': how to express that something must conform to a given format?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one is valid:

> A date field should be in a form 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

or

> A date field should be of a form 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

Comment: Try "in the form" ...

Comment: As in the question title, you probably want _format_ rather than _form_.

Comment: If you use "format", I'd put it after the format you want: "in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format".

Comment: @coleopterist Apparently, OP did not want to use the technical term *format* for obvious reasons. *Form* is acceptable as an alternative when addressing a lay reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*in the format* is the general expression used in the context.

The definite article *the* will be needed.

> A date field should be **in the** form 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

The alternate preposition *of* is acceptable in a similar way.

> A date field should be **of the** form 'MM/DD/YYYY'.